# How do I determine an HTML input element type upon an event using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given the following sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":input").blur(function(){
        alert("The input type is:" );  //How would this look??????
    })
});
```

How can I detemine whether this is an input, select, text, etc?

This is not a real-world example but should suffice for the purposes of this question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$(this).attr("type");
```

See jQuery's [Selectors/Attribute](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeHas#attribute) documentation for additional information.

Answer (score 5):

> *How can I deteminedetermine whether this is an input, select, text, etc?*

Note that `select`, `textarea`, "etc" elements are not covered by `$('input')`. You probably rather want to use [`$(':input')`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/input) to get them all.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':input').blur(function(){
        alert('The tag is:' + this.tagName);
        if (this.tagName == 'INPUT') {
           alert("The input type is:" + $(this).attr('type'));
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).attr("type");
```

for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").blur(function(){
        alert("The input type is:" + $(this).attr("type"));
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").blur(function(){
        var type = this.type;
        alert("The input type is:" + type);
    })
});
```

Comment: +1 of course this works, and doesn't waste time wrapping this in $ again

Answer (score 0):

Why not go through and see what attribute/property would be most useful?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").blur(function(){
        for (var x in this)
            alert(x + ":" + this[x]);
    })
});
```