# How to get type of input object

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I determine an HTML input element type upon an event using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940471/how-do-i-determine-an-html-input-element-type-upon-an-event-using-jquery)

I want to get type of input object but I alway got "undefined". 
What is missing it this code?

```
var c = $("input[name=\'lastName\']");
c.val("test");
alert(c.type);
```

My form

```
<form action="formAction.jsp" method="post">
    FirstName <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName"></input><br/>
    LastName <input type="text" name="lastName"></input><br/>
    Address <input type="text" name="address"></input><br/>
    Tel <input type="text" name="tel"></input><br/>
    Email <input type="text" name="email"></input><br/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$(c).attr('type')`

Comment: no need to wrap `c` in `$()` since it is already a jQuery object, but +1 for `attr` which is the answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
 var c = $("input[name=\'lastName\']");
```

To:

```
 var c = $("input[name='lastName']");
 alert(c.type);
```

...

Alternatively:

```
 alert($(c).attr('type'));
```

Comment: Escaping quotes that don't need escaping doesn't really do anything. Both of those lines behave identically.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery does not return an ordinary element object, which has its attributes as properties. It returns a jQuery wrapper; you can access its attributes using `attr()`, so what you want is:

```
alert(c.attr('type'));
```

Answer (score 1):

since you're using jQuery, you can do this:

`$( 'input[name="lastName"]' ).attr( 'type' );//returns text`